# Is it a requirement to define a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++

Do C++ destructors need to be defined as virtual? If so why? I've read that they need to be to ensure proper clean-up when one casts a base class pointer to a derived class.

Comment: Not required, but highly recommended.

Comment: Can you elaborate? An illustration would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A virtual destructor is required to allow dynamic dispatch of the destructor call to the proper class in the hierarchy tree.

In a situation in which you have:

```
Base *d = new Derived();
delete d;
```

without a `virtual` destructor you have undefined behavior. This because the compiler is not able to find the most specialized destructor for `Derived`, since it's not declared as `virtual`.

Answer (score 2):

It is not required formally - you can easily compile a class with virtual functions but not a virtual destructor, but that's unwise.

Imagine you have a base class A, and two derived classes B and C. B and C have different fields and need different cleanup in destructor.

Now you assign

```
A *p = new B();
```

Then, when you call

```
delete p;
```

The compiler wouldn't know which destructor to call (actually this is an undefined behaviour according to the C++ standard).

If you don't define a virtual destructor, only the destructor of A could be called, which is not sufficient in the case of our hypothetical class B.

If you never instantiate your class with a `new` keyword (and afterwards `delete` it) you don't need a virtual destructor. However, adding a virtual destructor doesn't affect the performance, so it's best to always provide it.